# Pandas Dataframe.resample('MS')

Tags: python, pandas

I wonder if somebody can help me understand where I may be going wrong. I have a dataframe which contains data (part numbers,sales per month, year) with missing months and I am trying to use *dataframe.resample('MS').asfreq()* to identify the missing months and insert them into my list. I have performed a *groupby* previously to ensure that data is collected together prior to the resample.
my code is:

```
df2=df1[['Part_ID','Order_Qty','Extended_Price','Month','Month1','Year']]
df2['Month1'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.Month.astype(str) +'-01-'+ df2.Year.astype(str))
df2=df2.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df2['Month1']))
df2=df2.groupby([df2['Part_ID'],df2['Year']])
df2=df2['Month1'].resample('MS').asfreq()
df3=df2.to_frame()
print(df3)
df4=df3.reset_index()
```

After execution some months have been added, but some are missing. Can anybody please explain why?

the output after resample is:

```
Part_ID                    Year            Month1
08095601/2                 2014 2014-07-01 2014-07-01
                                2014-08-01 2014-08-01
                                2014-09-01 2014-09-01
                                2014-10-01 2014-10-01
                                2014-11-01 2014-11-01
                           2015 2015-01-01 2015-01-01
                                2015-02-01 2015-02-01
                                2015-03-01 2015-03-01
                                2015-04-01 2015-04-01
                                2015-05-01 2015-05-01
                                2015-06-01 2015-06-01
08095601/5                 2014 2014-07-01 2014-07-01
                                2014-08-01 2014-08-01
                                2014-09-01 2014-09-01
                                              ...
ZZSSL                      2007 2007-10-01 2007-10-01
                                2007-11-01        NaT
                                2007-12-01 2007-12-01
                           2008 2008-01-01 2008-01-01
                                2008-02-01 2008-02-01
                                2008-03-01 2008-03-01
                                2008-04-01 2008-04-01
                                2008-05-01 2008-05-01
                                2008-06-01 2008-06-01
                                2008-07-01        NaT
                                2008-08-01        NaT
                                2008-09-01 2008-09-01
                                2008-10-01 2008-10-01
                           2009 2009-01-01 2009-01-01
                                2009-02-01 2009-02-01
                                2009-03-01 2009-03-01
                                2009-04-01 2009-04-01
                                2009-05-01 2009-05-01
                                2009-06-01 2009-06-01
                                2009-07-01 2009-07-01
bracket                    2014 2014-07-01 2014-07-01
                                2014-08-01 2014-08-01
                                2014-09-01 2014-09-01
                                2014-10-01 2014-10-01
                                2014-11-01 2014-11-01
                                2014-12-01 2014-12-01
                           2015 2015-01-01 2015-01-01
                                2015-02-01        NaT
                                2015-03-01        NaT
                                2015-04-01 2015-04-01
```

as you can see for part 08095601/2 in 2014 there is no month 12 and for part ZZSSL there is no month 11 OR 12. bracket has correctly inserted months 2 & 3 in 2015

Any pointers please.